# C# - How to draw open curves like closed curves?

Tags: c#, graphics, curve

I'm using DrawCurve and DrawClosedCurve to draw curves on my PictureBox like this:

```
if(isClosed) {
    g.DrawClosedCurve(
        new Pen(c, lineSize),
        points,
        tension,
        FillMode.Alternate
    );
} else {
    g.DrawCurve(
        new Pen(c, lineSize),
        points,
        tension
    );
}
```

The problem is, I'd like the open curves to look like the closed curves, because right now, if I use the same tension (0.8f) for both curves, they look like this:

[image: open curve and closed curve]

And what I really want is for it to look like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this result? Would I need to use DrawBezier (or DrawBeziers) instead of DrawCurve? If yes, how can I calculate the control points to use? Also, the tension must be ued so the user can draw different types of curves.

===== EDIT =====

I think I didn't manage to explain what I want properly, so I tried to think on another example...

There is this group of points:

[image]

Using 1.2f as tension, the DrawCurve draws it like this:

[image]

And the DrawClosedCurve like this:

[image]

And now I realized that I don't really want the open curve to be drawn like the closed curve, but what I really want to fix is the curve near the first point and the last point.

The curve starts by making an anticlockwise movement and them, switches to clockwise movement halfway to the next point. The same happens in the last point, but it starts clockwise from the penultimate point and switches to anticlockwise halfway to the next point (and this can also be seen on the first example). So, in this example, I'd like the curve to start with a clockwise movement without switching halfway to the next point and finish with a clockwise movement.

But now I don't think there is an easy solution for this, because I want the normal behavior from DrawCurve on all points but the first and the last...

I believe this can still be achieved by using DrawBezier, but I have no clue how to calculate the control points having the tension in mind...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Graphics.DrawArc`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142028(v=vs.110).aspx

"Draws an arc representing a portion of an ellipse specified by a Rectangle structure."

Just set startAngle to 0 and sweepAngle to 180

Comment: That wouldn't work for me because I need the tension, so, if the user uses 0.5f as tension, it would still appears as a portion of an ellipse when it shouldn't be like that...

Comment: @Thunderbert sry i misread your question. by "different types of curves" what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that everything is defined by the user, which means that the points are also input from the user, and he the user wants a particular group of points, it will mark it and will also inform the tension and if it is a closed or open curve.

Comment: @Thunderbert since the example you provided is very specific, and your definition general, the solution to that particular problem should be provided by the user (e.g. specify more points, type of arc, etc)

Comment: I added another example and explained better what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

DrawCurve() and DrawClosedCurve() will create cardinal splines, which is a special type of cubic Hermite splines where the tangent vectors are inferred from neighbor points. If you would like to be able to specify your own tangent vectors at first or last point (or at any point), you should use the more general cubic Hermite spline. Refer to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) for more details. You can convert cubic Hermite spline to cubic Bezier curve as

B0=P0  
B1=P0'/3 + B0 
B2=B3 - P1'/3 
B3=P1

where B0,B1,B2 and B3 are the control points for cubic Bezier curve, P0' and P1' are the tangent vector at point P0 and P1.